# Mysql Group By showing total of values in a column before counted values, how to stop this?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, grouping

Im working on a query to find duplicate values in a number of columns, so I will start by focusing on a single part of the query for a better explanation.

At the end of the day, All I need to know is if any of those 4 columns have a duplicate, and what column that duplicate is in.

here is the single query:

```
select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1;
```

So this works great, except the output is 2 rows. Looks like the first row is the total of hits >1 in the column, and then the next row is the actual duplicates count, like so:

```
cnt what_column
9440    CUST_REF
2   CUST_REF
```

My question is how can I just get that second row, without the total count of the column? (the value of 2 is correct for this column) I.e. I want only:

```
cnt what_column    
2   CUST_REF
```

Putting it together:

Im putting all these together with a `UNION` so for 4 columns it would be like this:

```
select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1
 union
 select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_PO' as what_column
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_po having count(cust_po) > 1
  union
 select count(*) as cnt, 'SHIP_BL' as what_column
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by ship_bl having count(ship_bl) > 1
  union
 select count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_SHIPID' as what_column
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_shipid having count(cust_shipid) > 1;
```

And the output of that renders the following, where I'd like to group ALL the fields that show duplicates together, and ALSO leave out that total count.

```
cnt what_column
9440    CUST_REF
2   CUST_REF
332 CUST_PO
3   CUST_PO
2   CUST_PO
8   CUST_PO
4   CUST_PO
9   CUST_PO
37  CUST_PO
6   CUST_PO
5   CUST_PO
7   CUST_PO
11  CUST_PO
6609    SHIP_BL
2   SHIP_BL
5   SHIP_BL
8   SHIP_BL
3   SHIP_BL
4   SHIP_BL
6   SHIP_BL
7   SHIP_BL
9183    CUST_SHIPID
2   CUST_SHIPID
3   CUST_SHIPID
6   CUST_SHIPID
```

Again, At the end of the day, All I need to know is that any of those 4 columns have a duplicate, and what column that duplicate is in.

**For those comments below**, I cannot share the table data. But let's look at it like this, after adding the column back to the select that is in the `HAVING`:

```
select cust_ref as val, count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
     from sometable 
      where status != 'whateverStatus' 
        and custm_id = 1234
     group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1;
```

All of the column names in the `HAVING` are actual column names in this table, the `what_column` is just an alias that shows me what column/query the dupe was found in.

so let's say the data looks like this, I have marked the dupes in the first 2 columns withthe *'s. I was hoping it would bold them:

```
id | cust_ref | cust_po | ship_bl |cust_shipid
997| **1234** | 9656    | 5656    | 9876
998| **1234** | **6353**| 2436    | 9394
999| 4327     | **6353**| 4388    | 4353
```

Im pretty sure I would end up with:

```
val cnt what_column
      3 CUST_REF
1234  2 CUST_REF
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: you should add the table schema  a clear data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: Can you show sample data and your table schema? I'm confused on what you are trying to accomplish here. If you show the actual column value, `select cust_ref,   count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column`, what do you get?

Comment: You are grouping by a field that is not selected - that's not a good thing.

Comment: Try wrapping your union in `select sum(cnt), what_column from (... ) as parts group by what_column`, you will probably find that each row is for a different cust_ref (for example), this will sum up the totals for all a particular type.

Comment: Guys, I've updated the question with some extra info after reading your comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: @NigelRen  could you possibly expand on your answer? Im not sure I understand exactly what you mean. a code sample would help lots! Thanks. What I actually came up with is:  select sum(cnt), what_column from(
 select cust_ref as val, count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
     from loadsh
      where status != 'DEAD' 
        and custm_id = 5692
     group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1
     ) as parts group by what_column; but that shows me 9442 | CUST_REF so this is a sum of the dupes with the rows.

Comment: Does your query actually give the 2 rows with your test data or is this what you think it will give?

Comment: it actually gives those 2 rows @NigelRen. If you look in the comment above, wrapping in what you described with actual data  gives: sum(cnt) what_column
9442 CUST_REF

Comment: I can't seem to get a totals row - I only get rows with duplicates - my SQL - `select cust_ref as val, count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column from t2 group by cust_ref having cnt > 1`

Comment: Can your columns contain nulls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187754/discussion-between-oman-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Your explanation of what appears to be a very simple problem is very convoluted, and you have not clearly explained what you want to count as a "duplicate" - do you want a count of the total records where a value appears more than once, or a count of the values which appear more than once?

You have further confused matters by confusing the count of duplicate values with a count of the domain - its just *coincidence* that the second row in the output of your query is 2 - this is not the value you are looking for, it just happens to be the same cardinal number.

> the value of 2 is correct for this column

This *suggests* you want the latter. In which case, since:

```
select  cust_ref, count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
from sometable 
where status != 'whateverStatus' 
   and custm_id = 1234
group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1;
```

will give you the former, you just need to count the number of rows output by that query. You can do this in 2 ways:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_values_in_more_than_row, what_column
FROM (
   select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column, cust_ref
   from sometable 
   where status != 'whateverStatus' 
      and custm_id = 1234
   group by cust_ref 
   having count(cust_ref) > 1
)
GROUP BY what_column
```

....or....

```
select  count(DISTINCT cust_ref) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
from sometable 
where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
group by cust_ref 
having count(DISTINCT cust_ref) > 1;
```

Comment: Your last code snippet produced no results, but the larger one above that gave me number_of_values_in_more_than_row what_column
94 CUST_PO
2 CUST_REF
10 CUST_SHIPID
26 SHIP_BL   - this looks correct!

Comment: Actually, this is not returning the correct result, if I remove all values for cust_ref from my data set (of which there were 1 set of dupes and 1 unique number), therefore making all values in the cust_ref field blank, the query still returns CUST_REF 1, like this number_of_values_in_more_than_row what_column
94 CUST_PO
1 CUST_REF
10 CUST_SHIPID
26 SHIP_BL why does it show 1, when there are no values in the column at all?

Answer (score 1):

You already have the duplicates figured out. So, if you only want the columns without the cnt column then do a subquery:

```
select distinct what_column 
 from (
select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column
from sometable 
 where status != 'whateverStatus' 
 and custm_id = 1234
group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1
union
 select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_PO' as what_column
 from sometable 
 where status != 'whateverStatus' 
  and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_po having count(cust_po) > 1
union
 select count(*) as cnt, 'SHIP_BL' as what_column
from sometable 
 where status != 'whateverStatus' 
and custm_id = 1234
 group by ship_bl having count(ship_bl) > 1
union
select count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_SHIPID' as what_column
  from sometable 
where status != 'whateverStatus' 
and custm_id = 1234
group by cust_shipid having count(cust_shipid) > 1);
```

Comment: so this returns each what_column. How can I know that its correct? if I add anything else into the select clause, i get the extra row back, but how can I be sure its not returning because the value is 9442, as opposed to 2?

Comment: You first have to figure out what the most amount of duplicates you can get other than the outliers. Then you filter on count. so where count < 11 (if 11 is the max amount of duplicates excluding outliers)

Answer (score 0):

The answer that ended up working was to use a having clause on the outer query, this returned what was needed with correct numbers:

```
SELECT sum(cnt) as dupes, COUNT(*) AS number_of_values_in_more_than_row, what_column
  FROM (
select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_REF' as what_column,cust_ref
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_ref having count(cust_ref) > 1
 union
 select  count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_PO' as what_column,cust_po
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_po having count(cust_po) > 1
  union
 select count(*) as cnt, 'SHIP_BL' as what_column,ship_bl
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by ship_bl having count(ship_bl) > 1
  union
 select count(*) as cnt, 'CUST_SHIPID' as what_column,cust_shipid
 from sometable 
  where status != 'whateverStatus' 
    and custm_id = 1234
 group by cust_shipid having count(cust_shipid) > 1
 )x
 GROUP BY what_column having count(number_of_values_in_more_than_row) >0;
```